FCM 404 'UNREGISTERED' Error for Specific Users Despite Token Update
I have written code to send push notifications using FCM. The user's push token is stored in the database, and if the token differs from the app instance's token, the token in the database is updated. The process works as follows: the token is retrieved from the database, and a POST request is made to:

https://fcm.googleapis.com:443/v1/projects/:projectId/messages:send

However, for some specific users (not all), I am receiving the following error:
{
    "error": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
        "status": "NOT_FOUND",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError",
                "errorCode": "UNREGISTERED"
            }
        ]
    }
}

What could be the possible reasons for this error?
I have read the official documentation regarding the 404 error in FCM, which mentions that this error occurs when the requested entity (the push token) was not found. Despite this, I am encountering this issue only with specific users, and I'm unsure why this is happening.
Initially, I thought the token was not being updated properly, but I have confirmed that the tokens are being updated correctly. I am aware that FirebaseInstanceId is deprecated, but it is still functioning correctly in my implementation.
Any insights on why this error might be occurring for certain users?
I tried using the "validate_only": true feature to check the tokens of users who were not receiving the notifications. However, even with validation, the messages were not sent, and the same error occurred. I was expecting the validation to confirm if the tokens were valid or not and to identify the root cause of the issue.

I attempted to verify the validity of the FirebaseInstance token by using the endpoint
GET https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/:IID_TOKEN?details=true.
The request returned the expected data, which suggests that the token is indeed valid. Can we confirm that this is a reliable method for validating the instance?
